# Unable to catch an exception while decoding a base64 string on Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, base64, decode

I'm trying to convert a base64 string in a BitMap, in order to show a photo in an ImageView. I'm failing because I'm receiving a bad string (how to fix this problem is not the scope of this topic), so I tried to handle this situation with a try-catch block.
Well, this block doesn't work because there's no exception throwed. As you can see from the Logcat in the lower part of the below image,the Base64 object (or the BitmapFactory one) just write a log about the failure (D/skia: failed to create image decoder with message 'unimplemented'), but don't launch any exception. There's no trace of my PHOTO-tagged log instead.
How could I do to manage this situation manually?

(I'm sorry if you'll find my english strange or difficult to read. I'm not mothertongue, but any help or criticism about it is well accepted)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it a compressed image encoded to Base64? (like `.jpg` or `.png`)
If so, the format of the image is not supported by the image decoder.

Otherwise, if it's raw data encoded in Base64, you should use `Bitmap.createBitmap()` to create a `Bitmap`.

Comment: I shoot a photo via a Node-RED node and pass it, after encoding, via MQTT to the Android app. I'm checking if the node applies some format to the image...anyway I'm not trying to solve it, but just to catch the situation I receive a bad string

Comment: I confirm that I send raw data. I solved the main problem, but still I'd like to know how to handle the situation where I receive a bad base64 string.